# Why we need add 1 to background brush color?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, graphics, gdi

One of member of the [WNDCLASS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/ns-winuser-tagwndclassa) structure is handle to the class background brush.

From description:

> This member can be a handle to the physical brush to be used for painting the background, or it can be a color value. A color value must be one of the following standard system colors (**the value 1 must be added to the chosen color**).

QUESTION:

Why must add 1 to this value?

Comment: Because for some historic reason that index is one-based instead of zero-based?

Comment: "Why must add 1 to this value?" Because the documentation tells you to do so.

Comment: To differenciate `NULL` and `COLOR_SCROLLBAR`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be because the `hbrBackground` field accept `NULL` value.

It's for `RegisterClass()` function to make the difference between `COLOR_SCROLLBAR` which is `0` and `NULL` which is an acceptable value.

Answer (score 1):

The `hbrBackground` member of the [`WNDCLASS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-wndclassw) structure has an overloaded meaning. It represents either one of:

- A handle to a brush
- A standard system color index

When using it to mean a brush handle, `NULL` (aka 0) is a valid value, meaning that erasing the background of a window is a no-op.

Unfortunately, 0 is also a valid system color index value (`COLOR_SCROLLBAR`). The consequence of this is that the ranges for the different meanings now overlap, and the system cannot disambiguate between them.

The solution is to offset one of those ranges so that they no longer overlap, and can be uniquely identified by the system. Adding 1 to the system color index does that, so that's why you have to add 1 when using a system color index.

---

Raymond Chen blogged about this a while ago: [Why do I have to add one when setting a class background brush to a system color?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20211220-00/?p=106044)